# How to convert RTF document to Google Document?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I have got Google's sample code working with an RTF file my application has created.  How can this RTF document be converted to a Google Document?

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('xxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

//Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//Insert a file
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('5.25.14-M02000-Ramin');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('application/rtf');

$data = file_get_contents('5.25.14-M02000-Ramin.rtf');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'application/rtf',
    ));

print_r($createdFile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an [optional parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) with your request.

```
convert boolean  
Whether to convert this file to the corresponding Google Docs format. (Default: false)
```

Something like this maybe, but I'm not sure your code is using the old Google API PHP client Lib.

```
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'application/rtf',
      'convert' => 'true'

    ));
```

Note: Yes I know you are following [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) example but unfortunately that uses the old Client lib.  I have been told they are in the process of updating it.  The new Google API PHP client lib can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). There is a file upload example there as well but its very basic.  [Fileupload.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/fileupload.php) and doesn't include the convert parameter either.

Comment: @DalmTo, you are right.  The only thing is that `'convert' => true` should be passed a boolean and not a string.  Thank you!